# Checking if the neighbors are the same in a 2d array from a specific point

Tags: java

I'm running into an issue when it comes to checking a from a specific point how many characters in a row are the same in all directions.

For example test for it would be:

```
assertEquals(2, game.getMaxSequence(0, 0, 0, 1, 'o'));
assertEquals(1, game.getMaxSequence(0, 0, 0, 1, 'x'));
```

I figured out how to do it with starting at the top left corner; however, when it comes to a specific point and to increment the parameters I am lost.

Here is the signature:

```
getMaxSequence(int row, int column, int dr, int dc, char symbol)
```

Thanks for the help.

Update, I got

```
 public int getMaxSequence(int row, int column, int dr, int dc, char symbol) {
    int maxSequence = 0;
    char[] rows = new char[row];
    char[] columns = new char[column];


    for(int i = 0; i < rows.length; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < dc; j++){
            for(int k = 0; k < dr; k++){

        if( rows[i] == symbol && columns[i] == symbol)
        {
            maxSequence++;//this should test to see if the index at this 
            //row is equal to what you pass it.
        }
        }
        }

}
    return maxSequence;
}
```

It isn't working still any suggestions?

Comment: So you want us to fill the method body in for you...? What do you need help with exactly?

Comment: I really don't know where to go with this, anything that would push me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple 2D array if you are having trouble visualizing it. The indices run from `0` to `n-1` where `n` is the length of the array.

```
[0][0]            [0][n-1]
    ┌───┬───┬───┬───┐
    │   │   │   │   │
    ├───┼───┼───┼───┤
    │   │   │   │   │
    ├───┼───┼───┼───┤
    │   │   │   │   │
    ├───┼───┼───┼───┤
    │   │   │   │   │
    └───┴───┴───┴───┘
[n-1][0]          [n-1][n-1]
```

We can pick any arbitrary point (call it `p`) and walk in any direction by incrementing/decrementing the indices (provided we must stay within the bounds of `0` to `n-1`).

```
 [x--, y--]      [y--]       [x++, y--]
            ┌───┬───┬───┬───┐
            │   │   │   │   │
            ├───┼───┼───┼───┤
            │   │   │   │   │
   [x--]    ├───┼───┼───┼───┤   [x++]
            │   │ p │   │   │
            ├───┼───┼───┼───┤
            │   │   │   │   │
            └───┴───┴───┴───┘
 [x--, y++]      [y++]       [x++, y++]
```

Once you can visualize it, this translates to a loop rather easily.

```
char[][] arr = ... ;

// increments are -1, 0 or 1
int xIncrement = ... ;
int yIncrement = ... ;

// starting coordinates
int x = pX;
int y = pY;

while( ( y < arr.length ) && ( x < arr[y].length ) ) {

    char c = arr[y][x];

    // do something with c

    x += xIncrement;
    y += yIncrement;
}
```

You could choose more complicated syntax (like `for` loops, `++`, `--`, etc) but that is a nice basic form.

In my diagram `p` corresponds to the indices `[2][1]`. If I wanted to walk from `p` to `[0][n-1]` (the "top-right" corner), the `x` increment would be `+1` and the `y` increment would be `-1`.

Comment: I don't know what the parameters to the method you are supposed to write mean (`dr`, `dc`, etc). Or what the rest of your code is. ; ) For example, I don't see a 2D array in your code. If you can explain it better I might be able to help further.